# Can't resolve maven dependency for denodo

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jdbc, denodo

I am trying to use denodo JDBC driver in my spring boot application. I downloaded the jar from the denodo site -> denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-8.0-update-20210715.jar

I'm using intelliJ and I have the dependency in the pom.xml file as such

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.denodo</groupId>
    <artifactId>denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-8.0-update-20210715</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

however the app can't resolve the dependency even though I added the jar to the project and I can see that the jar file is present in the External Libraries. I tried invalidating the caches and restarting.

I also tried mvn clean install -U, which threw another error: Failed to execute goal on project ...: Could not resolve dependencies for project ...: Could not find artifact com.denodo:denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-8.0-update-20210715.jar:8.0 in CompanyPublicGroup (artifactory.com/artifactory/CompanyPublicGroup)

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: The problem is that Denodo have not published that artifact to Maven Central.   So you have to **manually** download the JAR and add it to your local repo.  Or ... since you are apparently using a shared repo of some kind ... you talk to the people who manage it about adding the artifact there.

Comment: There are also questions on the Denodo community site about this.  And manual install to your local repo is what they recommend.

Comment: If they recommend to do that. That's wrong. They should distribute to Central repository. That makes it easier for consumers...